# Using Sympy to Solve Inverse Kinematic

Tags: sympy, inverse-kinematics

I want to solve simple 2D inverse kinematic problem with Sympy. I know forward kinematic equation of x and y position.

```
x = l1*cos(theta1) + l2*cos(theta1+theta2)
y = l1*sin(theta1) + l2*sin(theta1+theta2)
```

How to solve theta1 and theta2 value with Sympy if I know those two equations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution to those equations, but if there were you could use the follwing method:

```
import sympy as sp

# Define symbols
theta1, theta2, l1, l2, x, y = sp.symbols("theta1 theta2 l1 l2 x y")

# Define equations, rearranged so expressions equal 0
eq1 = l1 * sp.cos(theta1) + l2 * sp.cos(theta1 + theta2) - x
eq2 = l1 * sp.sin(theta1) + l2 * sp.sin(theta1 + theta2) - y

# Solve for theta1 & theta2
solution = sp.solve([eq1, eq2], [theta1, theta2], dict=True)
print(solution)
```

I was trying to use the sympy nonlinsolve solver for a similar inverse kinematics problem but noticed this comment in the [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/solvers.html):

> Currently nonlinsolve is not properly capable of solving the system of equations having trigonometric functions. solve can be used for such cases (but does not give all solution)